# Can't get the form to comment on posts

Tags: python, django

Ok this will be my last try, why I can't get the FormComment to comment a post in detail.html ? I'm getting nervous about this..

```
def DetailView(request, pk):
    if request.user.is_authenticated():
        base_template_name = 'blog/base.html'
    else:
        base_template_name = 'blog/visitor.html'
    post = get_object_or_404(Post, pk=pk)
    form = CommentForm(request.POST or None)
    if form.is_valid():
            comment = form.save(commit=False)
            comment.post = post
            comment.save()
            return redirect('blog:DetailView')
    return render(request,'blog/detail.html',{'post':post,'from':form ,'base_template_name':base_template_name})
```

form.py

```
class CommentForm(forms.ModelForm):
    class Meta:
        model = Comment
        fields = ('textc',)
```

And here the detail.html ( part of it)

```
{% if post.comment_set.all %}
                <h2>Comments</h2>
            <div class="comments">
            {% for comment in post.comment_set.all %}
                <span>
                <a href="">{{ comment.user }}</a> said on {{ comment.created_on }}
                    </span>
                <p>
            {{ comment.textc }}
                 </p>
                {% endfor %}
</div>
{% endif %}
                    <h4>Leave a Comment:</h4>
                    <form action="" method="POST">
                {% csrf_token %}
                <table>
                        {{ form.as_p }}
                </table>
                <input type="submit" name="submit" value="Submit" />
                </form>
                </div>
```

the CommentModel:

```
class Comment(models.Model):
    post = models.ForeignKey('blog.Post', null=True,related_name='comments')
    user = models.ForeignKey(User, max_length=200, blank=True, null=True)
    textc = models.TextField(null=True,max_length=200)
    created_date = models.DateTimeField(default=timezone.now)
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You have a typo in the last line of the view; you have `from` instead of `form` in the template context.

Comment: And now it's not working, I don't know how is that but when I submit now it shows me this error "Reverse for 'DetailView' with arguments '()' and keyword arguments '{}' not found. 0 pattern(s) tried: []" for this line "return redirect('blog:DetailView') "

Comment: I doubt that is the right value to use in the redirect - you should use the `name` argument of your url pattern.

Comment: yes, I just added 'pk = pk' now it woeks properly, thanks for your help :)